# Query to find rows which are not present for other IDs

Tags: sql, hive

I have table like below:

```
col1 col2 col3
A     1    3-March
A     1    4 March
A     1    7-march
A     2    3-March
A     2    5-March
A     2    7-march
```

In the table there can be multiple value can be present for col 1 like A,B,C,D
and for col2 like 1,2,3,4
Here I need rows where date is not present for other ID
For example, for col2 value 2, 4-March is not present but present in 1
Similarly 5-March is not presend for id 1 but it is for id 2.
I dont need 3 and 7 march because they are both presnt in id 1 and 2.
So My output will look like this:

```
A     1    5 March
A     2    4-March
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is not clear what the purpose of column1 is.  For instance, if the "2" rows were for `'B'`, what would the result be.  Also you use the terms `id` and `date`, but those are not columns in the data.

Comment: There can be multiple id for col1 like A,B,C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross join the distinct values of `col3` to the distinct values of `col1` and `col2` and then left join the table and filter out the matching rows:

```
select c12.col1, c12.col2, c3.col3
from (select distinct col3 from tablename) c3
cross join (select distinct col1, col2 from tablename) c12
left join tablename t
on t.col1 = c12.col1 and t.col2 = c12.col2 and t.col3 = c3.col3
where t.col3 is null
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hSYsgCfcCkRoscArpA41Mn/0) (for MySql but it is standard SQL).
Results:

```
| col1 | col2 | col3    |
| ---- | ---- | ------- |
| A    | 1    | 5-March |
| A    | 2    | 4-March |
```

Comment: your solution seesm correct if there is only one id in col 1 it will fail if ther is 2 or more distinct values in in col 1

Comment: @KumarHarsh Check this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hSYsgCfcCkRoscArpA41Mn/1 Does it fail?

Comment: It is giving 3 rows, for 1 it is correct but i am also getting row B,1,5,March. And B should not get dates from id A.

Comment: *I need rows where date is not present for other ID* do you think that you have explained your requirement correctly? Post sample data and expected results including other ids.

Comment: I changed croos to inner join and added col1 in c3 and added euqal condition.And it worked : 
select c12.col1, c12.col2, c3.col3
from (select distinct col1,col3 from tablename) c3
inner join (select distinct col1, col2 from tablename) c12 on c3.col1=c12.col1
left join tablename t
on t.col1 = c12.col1 and t.col2 = c12.col2 and t.col3 = c3.col3
where t.col3 is null

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would do in regular SQL.

```
select col1,col2,col3
  from tbl
 where col2=1
   and col3 not in (select col3 from tbl where col2=2)
union all
select col1,col2,col3
  from tbl
 where col2=2
   and col3 not in (select col3 from tbl where col2=1)
```

Comment: yeah but  i have like 8 ids not just 2, i just gave an example with 2

Answer (score 0):

If you have only two values in `col2`, the simplest method is aggregation:

```
select col1, (case when min(col2) = 1 then 2 else 1 end) as col2, col3
from t
group by col1, col3
having count(*) = 1;
```

For a more general solution, then you can use forpas's method of generating the full Cartesian product of `col2` and `col3` values and filtering out the ones that exist.

Comment: From the question: "I need rows where date is **not present** for other ID"